# Are questions about monopoly and what if a company bought this company on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Are questions that ask something like

> if Apple bought Android, would that be a monopoly?

That would be a monopoly, but are those kinds of questions allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it asks about a legal definition of.monopoly, yes. But rather than specific "would companies A and B merging create a monopoly?" - which are very limited use and become quickly outdated as markets change - they should be generalised to how it is determined that a monopoly definition is met, owhat conditions are required for preventing a potential monopoly, and use some companies as hypothetical examples.

Comment: Indeed, a reasonable question would be "how *does* the law define 'monopoly', and what are the sources of that definition?". It doesn't even touch the question of whether a monopoly is illegal -- is monopoly like porn (you know it intuitively when you watch it)?

Comment: @user6726 I think I got it except... the last part…

Comment: It's a reference to a famous quote by Justice Potter Stewart, and I'm particularly referring to the fact that like porn, "monopoly" is a subjunctive judgment.